# Notebook Clevo P955ER (Brazilian Avell A72) high fan speed on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, fan

My laptop is with a higher than usual fan speed in Ubuntu only. In a Windows 10 session the sound of the fan coolers seems lower

I installed a custom app https://github.com/SkyLandTW/clevo-indicator to set the fan speed in Clevo notebooks and found that the Core 0 temp is marking a whooping 80 celsius temp. But the other 5 cores are marking around 45 celsius

Answer (score 0):

I installed a newer kernel using ukuu app (https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu) and voilla! now the core temperatures are apparently showing ok. Now the cooler speed is behaving similar as it does on Windows 10. 
[screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yy1L.png)